# Making an Object3D "snap to grid"?

Tags: three.js

I made a Rubik's Cube in Three.js. One minor problem is that pieces gradually drift out of place due to accumulating rounding off errors. So after each completed 90° turn, I want to move it to *exactly* where it should be.

That place is well defined. All coordinates should be rounded to an integer, and all directions should point along the X, Y or Z axis. But I'm not sure how to do it correctly/safely.

If `obj.position` is (0.99999, 0, 0.00002) it's easy to move it to (1, 0, 0). But then there is `obj.matrix`, `obj.matrixWorld`, `obj.quaternion`, `obj.rotation` and several more, and I have no idea how all these interact and what's safe to do.

Is there a generic way to do this?

Comment: Your responsibility is to set `object.position` and either `object.rotation` (or `object.quaternion`). The renderer computes `object.matrix` and `object.matrixWorld` for you inside each render loop.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) can help you with the rounding.

An approach which might keep things a bit simpler is to not position the pieces and only rotate them (relative to the center of the cube). You'll need to position the the geometry in place first though without changing the center of rotation, and the easiest way to do that is probably:

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(x, y, z) );
```